# The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace. .NETCore - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: macos, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using a mac with visual studio 2017. I'm trying to start up a project with NuGet packages inside. When I right click on the source and go to update NuGet packages, I receive incompatible errors for 15 of the packages.

> Checking compatibility for System.Net.WebSockets 4.0.0 with
>   .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1. Incompatible packages: 15 Package restore
>   failed. Rolling back package changes for 'project.api'.

When I restore packages for the solution, it works successfully. When I go to build the project I get 28 errors. All with the same text -

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name '' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'project.api' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This issue does not persist on a counterparts Windows machine. I have no idea what to do or where to go.

Side note - unsure where to go to the NuGet package manager then go to package manager settings. This exists on windows but not Mac it seems.

Comment: I know it's a lot of packages, but (e.g. starting with just one) can't you remove and then reinstall, to see if at least the number of errors decreases?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version was not pushed to the repo. This was why I was getting the errors. So the build error is fixed but the update NuGet packages are still incompatible. Not going to worry about that for now.